# ngrx/data entity data service

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-ngrx-data

Trying to understand the ngrx/data entity data service example [here](https://ngrx.io/guide/data#creating-entity-data-services), where it says "Creating entity data services". After showing that service, the docs go on to show how to use ngrx/data in components. The part of the component I'm interested in is this:

```
getHeroes() {
  this.heroService.getAll();
}
```

The docs state that `getAll()` initiates an HTTP request, but I'm not sure where or how this request is actually made. In the [ngrx-data repo](https://github.com/johnpapa/ngrx-data-lab). It states to replace the heroService with the following code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  EntityCollectionServiceBase,
  EntityCollectionServiceElementsFactory
} from 'ngrx-data';
import { Hero } from '../core';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class HeroService extends EntityCollectionServiceBase<Hero> {
  constructor(serviceElementsFactory: EntityCollectionServiceElementsFactory) {
    super('Hero', serviceElementsFactory);
  }
}
```

The docs state `ngrx-data handles getting and saving our data for us`. That's great, but I don't know where this getting data is happening. I cloned the repo, checked out the `finish` branch and could not find something that is hitting endpoints.

E.g. the service used to call `http.get(${api}/heroes)` for `getAll()` to get all the heroes, but that's replaced by the above code, so where are these calls occurring?

I notice that the `EntityCollectionServiceBase` has a `getAll()` method. But where is the configuration of this service taking place to register the respective endpoints? I'm sure that I am missing something incredibly simple here.

Answer (score 4):

Broadly speaking the `EntityCollectionServiceBase` dispatches **actions** and via the persist **effect** in `EntityEffects` the `DefaultDataService` is called and maps the response to its success / fail actions. See [Architecture Overview](https://ngrx.io/guide/data/architecture-overview)

Hence if you want to access / transform the data returned from the API you extend / replace the `DefaultDataService`. You can register your custom data service using `EntityDataService` which is basically a registry of data services that gets or creates the data service (uses default if none exists).

[image]

Comment: side question, what did you use to create this flowchart?

Comment: @altu draw io (now changed url)

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at the docs, it would appear that the [DefaultDataService](https://ngrx.io/guide/data/entity-dataservice) 
"Composes HTTP URLs from a root path and the entity name"

The docs also recommend checking out the [Configuration](https://ngrx.io/guide/data/entity-dataservice#configure-the-defaultdataservice) section below in the docs to specify your own urls for the Entity DataService to interact with.

You can probably see the generated endpoints in use in the Network tab of dev tools while playing with the example app.

I hope this helps.

Comment: the api always hit the port of angular, how to hit with my own API ?

Comment: Make sure you registered a root url with DefaultDataServiceConfig

const defaultDataServiceConfig: DefaultDataServiceConfig = {
  root: {environment.your_base_url},
  ...
}

and in your app module
 {
      provide: DefaultDataServiceConfig,
      useValue: defaultDataServiceConfig
  }

Answer (score 1):

You can register provider for it in app.module

```
  providers: [
{ provide: DefaultDataServiceConfig, useValue: defaultDataServiceConfig } ]

export const defaultDataServiceConfig: DefaultDataServiceConfig = {
root: 'myapi/baseurl',
timeout: 1000 * 60, // request timeout }
```

Answer (score 0):

HttpClient requests are made in `DefaultDataService.execute()`. To make these requests the `DefaultDataService` instance uses an `HttpClient` instance that was injected into the `DefaultDataServiceFactory` instance used to create it (to create the `DefaultDataService` that is).

As other users have suggested you can provide alternative `DefaultDataServiceConfig` to `DefaultDataServiceFactory` that will be used by `DefaultDataServiceFactory.create<T>()` to create the `DefaultDataService`. For example, you could change the root path of `api` to a full endpoint of your choosing such as `https://my-endpoint/`. Note that because ngrx/data's default endpoint path is `api` the `HttpClient` will recognise this as a relative path and use the default protocol + host + port - so if you're running in angular dev mode it will be `localhost:4200`.

If you want more control over the http requests you could also use a custom `DataServiceFactory` by extending `DefaultDataServiceFactory` and injecting your own `HttpClient` instance - this way you can also hook up interceptors if you have more complex needs.